# Properly MySQL relating one table row to two other table rows

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am not super experienced in MySQL, and am building a simple CRM for a client. Originally based on his ideas of how it would work I set up the database structure like below, so each Account could have multiple contacts connected to it, and I related them simply by using the matching account number. Easy-peasy.

```
Account Table
+-------------+-------------+
| account_id  | create_date |
+-------------+-------------+
|#10045       | 01/05/15    |
|#10046       | 01/07/15    |
+-------------+-------------+

Customer Contact Table
+-----------+-----------+-----------+ 
|contact_id |account_id |first_name |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|#124       |#10045     |John       |
|#125       |#10045     |Bill       |
|#126       |#10046     |Frank      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

But further into the project I find out he wants the contacts to be reusable on other accounts, and not have to create duplicates.  So relating simply by account number as above won't work.

So I was thinking that I would remove the "account_id" row from the contact table, and use a third table like below.

```
Account Contact Link Table
+--+------------+------------+
|id| account_id | contact_id |
+--+------------+------------+
|#1| #10045     | #124       |
|#2| #10045     | #125       |
|#3| #10046     | #126       |
+--+------------+------------+
```

That will work, but I am wondering if this is best practice.

Comment: so it means 'Jhon' and 'Bill' can have the same account right? In that case your approach is correct since u have resolved many-to-many relationship between account and contact table by creating a mapping table (Account Contact Link Table)

Comment: Right!,  So then the best thing here is for the contact link table to use FKs to ref the IDs  right?

Comment: yes that's the correct way. your `Account Contact Link Table` will hold all the relationships between `account` and `contact` tables. it can be easily seen in an ER diagram if u have designed one